# Getting server time freezes and crashes my application

Tags: android, multithreading, time, android-asynctask

I am doing an app where I click the START button and get current time, and hitting STOP gets the time again. I´ve been using system time without any errors, recently I changed it to server time, which is in an Asynctask, but the app is unstable since, slowed down and exits without error messages, but on faster connections it can process. Any idea why?  This is my code:

```
class getDST2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {



    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        try {
            TimeTCPClient client = new TimeTCPClient();
            try {
                client.setDefaultTimeout(60000);
                client.connect("time.nist.gov");
                simpledate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                do_casu = simpledate.format(client.getDate());
            } finally {
                client.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        getDSTdone = true;
    }
}
```

Also doing a graphic timer of the current time since Start was clicked so I need to get server time every second inside a handler.. code:

```
    handler.post(r = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {

   hasStartedtt2 = true;
   calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   simpledate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

  new getDST2().execute(); // THIS IS THE ASynctask, returns the "do_casu" String


 zaciatok_hour = zaciatok.substring(11, 13);
 zaciatok_minute = zaciatok.substring(14, 16);
 koniec_hour = do_casu.substring(11, 13);
 koniec_minute = do_casu.substring(14, 16);
 zaciatok_sekundy = zaciatok.substring(17, 19);
 koniec_sekundy = do_casu.substring(17, 19);


 final_hour = ((Integer.parseInt(koniec_hour) - Integer.parseInt(zaciatok_hour)));
 final_minute = Integer.parseInt(koniec_minute) - Integer.parseInt(zaciatok_minute);
final_seconds = Integer.parseInt(koniec_sekundy) - Integer.parseInt(zaciatok_sekundy) - 1;

           }
           });
```

Handler is called every second.

Comment: Can you please post a full example? You are reading from and writing to fields that are not declared, like `time` and `from_time`.

Comment: they are declared in the constructor, time is a type Date and from_time is String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ServerTimeThread sth = new ServerTimeThread();
 sth.start();
 from_time = simpledate.format(sth.time);
```

when you call 'sth.time',the thread just start and is still in progress.

'time' is remain uninitialized,it is init at end of thread

So when accessing 'time',it is null absolutely.

2 way for AsyncTask

Blocking operation:

```
public class NTPDateTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Date> {
@Override
   protected Date doInBackground(Void... voids) {
      Date date=fetchYourDate();
      //fetch your date here
      return date;
   }
}
```

then call

```
Date result = new NTPDateTask().execute().get();
```

Non-Blocking operation(Callback pattern):

```
    public class NTPDateTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Date> {
    @Override
    protected Date doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Date date = fetchYourDate();
        //fetch your date here
        return date;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Date date) {
        //this is 'callback'
        //do the thing you want when task finish
        //onPostExecute is called when doInBackground finished,and it runs on UIThread
    }
}
```

then

```
new NTPDateTask().execute();
```

EDIT:

```
class TCPTimeDisplayWorker implements Runnable {

static SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");

boolean isActive = true;
private Handler targetHandler;

public TCPTimeDisplayWorker(Handler targetHandler) {
    //pass the handler ref here
    this.targetHandler = targetHandler;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (isActive) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Date date = fetchDateFromTCPClient();
        //fetch Server Date here

        String currentDateText = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
        targetHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(targetHandler, 0, currentDateText));
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long lapse = endTime - startTime;
        if (lapse < 1000) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 - lapse);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Handler:

```
 // Non-static inner class will hold outer-class reference,may risk in memory leak
static class MainHandler extends Handler {
    private WeakReference<TextView> textViewWeakReference;
    // declare as WeakRef to avoid memory leak

    public MainHandler(Looper looper, WeakReference<TextView> textViewWeakReference) {
        super(looper);
        this.textViewWeakReference = textViewWeakReference;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (textViewWeakReference.get() != null) {
            //handle the message from message queue here
            String text = (String) msg.obj;
            textViewWeakReference.get().setText(text);
        }
    }
}
```

then

```
    // must use the same handler to send msg from Background thread and 
    // handle at Main Thread
    // a handler create on a thread will bound to that thread


    mainHandler = new MainHandler(Looper.getMainLooper(), new WeakReference<>(mTextViewSystemTime));
    new Thread(new TCPTimeDisplayWorker(mainHandler)).start();
```

btw,CamelCase is the common naming convention in Java.

Hope these are helpful.

Comment: I tried your examples, my app still crashes after executing the code in most cases, sometimes it freezes for a while but works on, there are several other asynctasks going on with data exchange with DB, thats why I wanted it to be done inside a thread instead of asynctask. Somehow I want to maximize performance.

Comment: Any AsyncTask is just a higher level encapsulation of Thread.
The reason why your app freezes seems like that something else doing a lot on your UI Thread(aka Main Thread),there are tests your have to do to find out the crash and freeze cause.
If you want to optimize the performance, you may try Callback Pattern in pure thread

Comment: I found the source of the problem. I have a piece of code where I want to get the current system time every second inside a `Handler` to display time spent since clicking start button. So I figure I cant call Asynctask every second, as usually the first isnt even finished when I call the second, leaving the string I want to display null, and .get() would freeze the UI for 4ever. Is there any way to display server time every second with the least performance drop?

Comment: So I can take the code out from asynctask and put it inside the handler and I wont get the getting system time on main thread error? Can you show an example how you meant it please?

Comment: Sorry I didn't know Server time will be fetch at each second,not once.
AsyncTask is eazy to use but expensive,continuous process should not be done inside.
I still not understand your problem really clear,pasting the code here could help much more,thx.

Comment: Updated OP to be more specific

Comment: I am going to go ahead and accept the answer, but I will still need some time to figure it out as I am new to this. Thanx

Comment: Glad to provide some help.